# Unity Services - No available projects under organization

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to enable Unity Analytics for a project within an organization. So, following the [instructions](https://docs.unity3d.com/520/Documentation/Manual/UnityAnalyticsCopyProjectID.html) in the documentation, I opened the *Services* tab, clicked *I already have a Unity project ID* (I can see from the web dashboard that we have one) and select my organization from the first dropdown. I expected to see the organization's Unity projects in the second dropdown but it's just empty.

The organization doesn't appear at all in the dropdown for *Create a Unity Project ID*, I assume because I'm not an administrator or because all the projects already have Unity Project IDs (they do).

[image]

This screenshot shows the empty project dropdown.

I can edit almost anything through the web dashboard (though I'm not a full admin) so I find it weird that no projects are showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a permissions thing. Apparently, only the true admin can link with unity services, editor roles are out of luck.

[image: screenshot: Unable to linked project to Unity Services]